# selectionChanged on specific items

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I have an eclipse plugin which has multiple classes which make some UI contributions.

The contribution is done through the deprecated `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets` and the classes implement the `IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate` which require an implementation of the `selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection)`.

The `selectionChanged` method is triggered on any selection change (another file opened, another item selected in Project Explorer, **some text is selected in the editor**(this one triggers several calls of the method)).

Is there a filtering or something which I can do to limit the `selectionChanged` observed objects. For example, for `class A`, trigger the `selectionChanged` only if the opened file in editor changes)?

Comment: No, there is no way to filter that.

Comment: @greg-449 That's unfortunate :( Do you think that checking the  `selection.getClass()` value to remove the overhead is a proper aproach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to filter that.

Selections coming from text editors with be instances of `ITextSelection`, other selections will usually be instances of `IStructuredSelection` so you can check for those instances to do simple filtering in your code.